# Can't size my div with <a>

Tags: html, css, styling

So I have 3 divs next to each other just how I want.
However when I add the  element the sizing and margins get all messy.
I know you have to have the links display set to block but that doesn't fix it, I've tried some things but all of that didn't help. I'd like to keep the margins and size the same for all the links.

[image: This is what i get]
[image: This is what I want]

HTML:

```
    <div id="submenu">
        <div id="items">
            <a href="index.html"><div id="item1"><p>HOME</p></div></a>
            <a href="overons.html"><div id="item2"><p>OVER ONS</p></div></a>
            <a href="contact.html"><div id="item3"><p>NEEM DIRECT CONTACT OP</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#submenu {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 130px;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 1400px; 
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

#items {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#item1, #item2, #item3 {
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: 'roboto';
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;

}

#items a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;

}

#item1:hover, #item2:hover, #item3:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE8 */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.1, SizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE6 and 7 */ 
}

#item1 {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#item2 {
    background-image: url(placeholder2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

#item3 {
    background-image: url(placeholder3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin-right: 0px;

}
```

Comment: Do you have * { box-sizing: border-box; } at the top of css ?? I am not able to understand your problem but what border-box would do is that all the padding and borders would be included inside your div width and height.

Comment: @JotWaraich Thanks for you comment! i added it but that doesn't really help. DId you see the images?

Comment: I would suggest to make div outer elements in html and then inside of them add <a> tags. Make the <a> inline block elements and give them width and height 100% ensuring that div has the width and height as in your current css. Also i thing i noticed is that the items has width 1300px but its children have width greater than it 1350px plus the margins. You have to calculate the widths according to the width of parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `flex-direction: row;` after `display: flex;` in #items

and to your #image

```
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 300px; 
max-height: 300px;
```